# How to avoid loop transforming a matrix using a function for each elements

Tags: r

Well, I have a matrix, let's say "A" (5x3). Each column is a variable and each row is an observation.
My goal is to clean the data in A respect to those observations that exceed the 75% quantile for each variable assigning the value of quantile.

I tried to use the "APPLY" function defining a FUN with a vector as input but it doesn't work.

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15

f2 <- function(x1, x2) {
  if (x1>x2){
    return(x2)} else {
      return(x1)
    }
  }

B <- apply(A, 1:2, FUN = f2, x2=apply(A, 2, quantile, probs=0.75))
```

I want to get a matrix like this:

```
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    4    9   14
```

But I got this warnings:

```
There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> B
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] 1         3         Numeric,3
[2,] 2         4         Numeric,3
[3,] 3         Numeric,3 Numeric,3
[4,] 4         Numeric,3 Numeric,3
[5,] Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do the following:

```
A <- matrix(c(1:5,3,4,8,9,10,5,6,13,14,15),ncol = 3)
q <- apply(A, 2, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 0.75))
A <- sapply(1:ncol(A), function(x) ifelse(A[,x] > q[x], q[x], A[,x]))
```

**Output**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    4    9   14
```

Comment: Really a smart answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only by working on the columns. Each column is a vector, and you can subselect the values above the quantile to replace them by the quantile:

```
A <- matrix(c(1:5,3,4,8,9,10,5,6,13,14,15),ncol = 3)

apply(A,2,function(col){
  col[col > quantile(col,probs = 0.75)] <- quantile(col,probs = 0.75)
  col
  })

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    4    9   14
```

Comment: Observe that you compute quantiles twice in your code. This may be expensive for large matrices